# How to run a job (dll) in the background c# mvc

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, dll, console-application

I have written a console app, compiled as a dll that can take up to six hours to run.

As I use quartz for other scheduled jobs, I feel confident that I can schedule this process to run on a schedule using quartz.

However, the schedule would be hardcoded. Is there a way to schedule a quartz job dynamically thorough our web site?

More importantly, I also need to give the customer the option to run this process at will.  While I can call the dll from the web site, I need for it to run if the user closes the browser.  Or in the background so the user can go on to other tasks.

I have looked into Hangfire but it is not approved for our network.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to run the task in .Net (non Core)

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_=> LongRunningMethod());
Return View();
```

If you are using .Net Core, Use this and don't await for the Task to complete.

```
Task.Run(() => LongRunningMethod());
Return View();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this!

Comment: I have this working, to a point.  The issue I have is that my process can run as long as six hours.  I cannot change the  idle time-out property of IIS.   Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) in .net core. It also support long running task.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this!